# why mysql just listen on ipv6's port 3306 , not a ipv4's port 3306

Tags: mysql

I just got a mysql  problem .
when I start the mysql service with command

```
# service mysqld start
```

and the mysql service just listen on a IPv6's port 3306 which I though would be a IPv4's  port 3306.

```
➜  ~ netstat -ntpl | grep 3306
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1897/mysqld
➜  ~
```

the my.cnf is follows:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

system : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
mysql version: mysqld  Ver 5.6.35 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

would someone do me a favor and find out how I can change it to listen on IPv4's 3306, thanks a lot .

Comment: what 127.0.0.1:3306 returns?

Comment: This question should be on ServerFault, and you forgot to tell us your MySQL version and operating system.

Comment: But the short answer is that you or someone else must have configured the service startup script to make this occur. The default in MySQL is IPv4 only. Who is your system administrator? How was the product installed?

Comment: Can you connect through ipv4? Maybe it's just netstat bug?

Answer (score 8):

I spent a few hours and found solution at last!

In .cnf file must be bind-address=0.0.0.0

but not *, not 127.0.0.1, not client_address

I don't know why, but only 0.0.0.0 get to me:

```
netstat -a | grep mysql

  tcp mysql

else tcp6 mysql
```

Wishes!!!

Answer (score 1):

sorry , I think the IPv4 's port 3306 is open , and the result I saw from command isn't true .

when I test the port , It can be connected.

```
➜  ~ telnet 115.*.*.222 3306
Trying 115.*.*.222...
Connected to 115.*.*.222.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
5.6.35"+d:0$bB�K.DH!fc;?hotmysql_native_password^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```