# Lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My customer's BlueHost web server got hacked and somehow injected with malware. That was removed/fixed by using SiteLock, but in the midst of that "fix", remote connections to the MySQL database was broken. The error:

> Lost connection to server at 'handshake: reading initial communication
> packet', system error: 0

[image]

I have looked carefully at [this similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755819/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-at-reading-initial-communication-packet-syste) and none of the suggested solutions worked, which I will comment on individually:

1. The website is still able to query the database--it is only remote connections that fail (see error message posted above).
2. My customer connects with `Workbench` and I use `HeidiSQL`. We are both on different sides of the country and both our clients fail to connect. Before the hack and sitelock repair, it worked for both of us with both of our clients.
3. It is not a client-side firewall problem. Nothing has changed on the client side of either my customer or me. But changes were made on the server.
4. In `my.cnf` there is no `bind-address` setting. Here are all the `my.cnf` settings:

[image]

5. I confirmed through `Terminal` that MySQL is still running on port 3306:

[image]

6. My client called BlueHost and asked if they were blocking connections to/from port 3306 and they said no. (Is there a way I can verify this?) I ran `telnet mycustdomain.com 3306` from a windows command shell and it opened an active connection for me. No errors about connection closed, etc.

What can I do to discover the cause of this error, and how can I fix it?

** EDIT **

I tried adding `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` but that made no difference - same error.

Comment: easleyfixed: Isn't that what my `telnet` connection already proved? Can you give the syntax of what sort of ping you mean?

Comment: Yeah sorry I just saw that part, sorry about that, .. did some research and MAYBE its related to this issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309187/django-exception-value-2013-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-que

Granted thats Django but maybe there is something here to consider.

Comment: Something to do with : mysql-connector-python being glitchy.

Comment: Nothing to do with python or django, I had already seen that post earlier but it was unrelated to my issue.

Comment: Technically not true .. Workbench is written in Python .. so there may still be something there .. and its a connection issue .. so still think you might want to look into this one more.

Comment: The point is, the problem isn't python; the problem is that the connection is being blocked by the server somehow.

Comment: If you can ping it and it goes through ... then its not being blocked ... the connection is failing... likely because of the mysql_connect-Python issue ..  I suspect what ever exploit they used to derp up the site probably derped up that connection as a side effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252282/discussion-between-herrimancoder-and-easleyfixed).

Comment: the line you showed as proove for a listening mysqld is a TCPV6 entry ... is your client (and you) really using the V6 IP to connect from remote? Please check if the server also listens on V4

Comment: Synopsis, that's a bit beyond me. How can I check if server listens on V4, and if not, how can I enable that?

Comment: Synopsis, is this relevant to my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597567/why-mysql-just-listen-on-ipv6s-port-3306-not-a-ipv4s-port-3306 - Should I add a `bind-address`  of `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I tried adding the `bind-address` and it changed nothing. Although I can telnet to that port on the server from my local dev box, something is blocking remote connections.